# ID not found in layout > when I want to click on the submit button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This is what I get in my errors tab,when open I  the localhost.What could I do to fix this error?

Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
"submit_button_test"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.

If you are assigning callbacks to components that are
generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the
initial layout), you can suppress this exception by setting
`suppress_callback_exceptions=True`.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
alert7.children

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import datetime
#import connect
import pandas as pd
from app import app
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import dash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import distutils.dist
import utils
import constants
import mssql_queries
import mssql_conn
import mysql_queries
import base64
import io
import flask 
import os
import sys
from waitress import serve
import json
#import kaleido
import plotly
import base64
from app import app
import utils
import mysql_queries
import mssql_queries
import mssql_conn
import constants

def convert_timedelta(timedelta):
    total_seconds = timedelta.total_seconds()
    hours = int(total_seconds // 3600)
    minutes = int(total_seconds // 60 % 60)
    seconds = int(total_seconds % 60)
    if hours < 10:
        hours = "0" + str(hours)
    if minutes < 10:
        minutes = "0" + str(minutes)
    if seconds < 10:
        seconds = "0" + str(seconds)
    return str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds)

controls = dbc.FormGroup(
    [
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
            html.Div(["Start Time: ", constants.start_date_picker],
                    ),
                ),
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([ constants.start_time_picker ])
            )
        ],style={"marginBottom":"0.5em"}),
                dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
            html.Div(["End Time: ", constants.end_date_picker]),
                ),
            dbc.Col(constants.end_time_picker ),
        ]),
    html.Hr(),
    dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
                     html.Div(["Planned Qty"]),
             ]),
         dbc.Col([
                    dcc.Input(id="planned_qty", type="text", persistence=True, required=True),
             ])
     ],style={"marginBottom":"0.5em"}
     ),
    html.Hr(),
    dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
                     html.Div(["Database"])
             ]),
         dbc.Col([
                     constants.database
             ])
     ],style={"marginBottom":"1em"}),          
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
                    html.Div(["Type"])
            ]),
        dbc.Col([
                    constants.part_type_selection
            ])
    ],style={"marginBottom":"1em"}),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
                    html.Div(["Worker Name"])
            ]),
        dbc.Col([
                    constants.worker_selection
            ])
    ],style={"marginBottom":"1em"}),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
                    html.Div(["Language"])
            ]),
        dbc.Col([
                    constants.language
            ])
    ],style={"marginBottom":"0.5em"}),
    html.Hr(),
    dbc.Button(
        id='submit_button_test',
        n_clicks=0,
        children='Submit',
        color='primary',
        block=True
        ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id="alert31"),
    html.Div(id="alert32"),
    html.Div(id="link7")
    ]
)

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2('Quantity and Scrap', style=constants.TEXT_STYLE),
        html.H3('Parameters', style=constants.TEXT_STYLE),
        html.Hr(),
        controls

    ],
    style=constants.SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

content = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Tabs([
            dcc.Tab(label='Bar Chart', children=[
                dcc.Store(id="query_output"),
                dcc.Store(id="shift_filter"),
                dcc.Store(id="excel_data31"),
                dcc.Store(id="excel_data32"),
                dcc.Graph(id="bar_chart", style={"height":800}),
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.Div(children=html.Strong(id='good_parts'))
                    ]),
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.Div(children=html.Strong(id='bad_parts'))
                    ]),
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.Div(children=html.Strong(id="total_parts"))
                    ])
                ])
            ]),
            dcc.Tab(label='Pie Chart', children=[
                dcc.Graph(id="pie_chart", style={"height":800}),
            ]),
        ]),
    ],
    style=constants.CONTENT_STYLE,
    id="content"
)


layout = html.Div([sidebar, content])

def boolean_helper(selector):
    if len(selector) > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@app.callback(
    [Output("alert7", "children")],
        Input("submit_button_test", "n_clicks"),
        state=[
            State("start_date_picker", "date"),
            State("start_time_picker", "value"),
            State("end_date_picker", "date"),
            State("end_time_picker", "value"),
            State("database", "value")
            ])

def show_erros(n_clicks, start_date_picker, start_time_picker, end_date_picker, end_time_picker, databse):
    print("asdf")
    if n_clicks:
        start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date_picker, "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(start_time_picker[0:2]))
        end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_picker, "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(end_time_picker[0:2]))
        parameters = [start_time, end_time]
        print("is executed")
        query_string = mssql_queries.build_db_query_string_app7()
        records = mssql_conn.execute_query(query_string, parameters, str(databse))


        #query_string = mysql_queries.build_db_query_string_app7(str(database), str(language))
        #records = connect.execute_query(query_string, parameters, str(database))
        if records:
            dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
            print(dataframe)
            return None
```

this is my index.app

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from app import app
from apps import app1, app2, app3, app4, app5, app6, app7
import nav

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return nav.layout
    elif pathname == '/apps/Downtime_and_Reasons':
        #app.title = "Downtime and Reasons"
        return app1.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/Report_of_Check_Criteria":
        #app.title = "Report of Check Criteria"
        return app2.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/Quantity_and_Scrap":
        #app.title = "Quantity and Scrap"
        return app3.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/User_Log":
        #app.title = "User Log"
        return app4.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/Error_Log":
        #app.title = "Error Log"
        return app5.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/Error_Log":
        #app.title = "Error Log"
        return app5.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/Parameter_Log":
        return app6.layout
    elif pathname == "/apps/app7":
        return app7.layout
    else:
        return '404'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8080)
```

#app.run_server(host="10.3.41.18", port=8080, debug=False)

Comment: It's not clear where you are defining the app layout in your code, but it seems that the items in the `controls` list (which includes the button with `id= "submit_button_test"`) are not rendered in the layout (which is why the callback is throwing an error).

Comment: what could I do to fix  it?

Answer (score 0):

It works,when I added the followng code:

```
dbc.Button(

        id='submit_button',

        n_clicks=0,

        children='Submit',

        color='primary',

        block=True

        ),

    html.Hr(),

    html.Div(id="alert7"),

    html.Div(id="alert12"),

    html.Div(id="alert13"),

    html.Div(id="link7"),

    html.Div(id="link12")
```